# MySQL How To Upload CSV dates from 'mm/dd/yyyy' directly into a DATE data type format

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

I upload daily sales data into MySQL (Workbench) (AWS). Right now, our method of uploading regular dates like 5/10/2023 is to keep ANY AND ALL columns that include dates as a data type of VARCHAR. As a result I can't use any DATE keywords/ranges, and we've had a number of typos that have had to be manually corrected.

I want to change all our tables to DATE data types, and my boss is a purist and wants the dates to directly load dates like 5/10/2023 format into MySQL dates converted directly to 2023-05-10. This seems like an easy task, but I cannot figure it out after several tests, mostly involving STR_TO_DATE  and DATE_FORMAT functions. I feel like I'm close but a little off in my syntax somewhere

**CSV Input File shows as date_col = 5/10/2023**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/LK/Desktop/Date Import Test.csv'
INTO TABLE Test_Table
    
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS

(date_col, blah_col1, blah_col2)
SET date_col = STR_TO_DATE(date_col,'%m/%d/%Y');
```

On that last line, I've also attempted this variation:

```
SET ld_new = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(ld_new, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Everything ends up uploading as either NULL or 0000-00-00.

I want the result to be `2023-05-10`, recognized by MySQL as a proper date data type.

Comment: Review the section headed **Input Preprocessing** here- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a user variable in the column list.

```
(@date_col, blah_col1, blah_col2)
SET date_col = STR_TO_DATE(@date_col,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Before starting applying mentioned below, please create a backup of your tables and verify that all date values are in a consistent format. Here is the link how to do: [backup](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-backup-restore-a-mysql-database)

1. First, you need to modify your existing tables to change the `VARCHAR` columns containing date values to the `DATE` data type. You can do this using the `ALTER TABLE` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name
MODIFY date_col DATE;
```

1. Now, you can change `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` query to import the CSV file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/LK/Desktop/Date Import Test.csv'
INTO TABLE Test_Table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@date_col, blah_col1, blah_col2)
SET date_col = STR_TO_DATE(@date_col, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

This query reads the data from your **CSV** file and maps the columns to the target table. The `@date_col` variable is used to temporarily store the date values from the **CSV** file, which are then converted to the correct `DATE` data type using the `STR_TO_DATE()` function with the format **%m/%d/%Y**.
After the conversion, the date values should be stored in the MySQL table as a proper `DATE` data type, and by default, MySQL represents dates in the **YYYY-MM-DD** format.